# Apache Mod Rewrite does not rewrite file name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i have the following problem:

On the download dialog on each browser it displays me only the dot extension filename 
like .divx

But i want the full name eg

http://example.com/14558/.divx rewrites to 14558.divx and not onyly .divx

I want see on every browser dialog the number and the extension.
like 14558.divx

How i can solve this problem ??

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/.divx$ $1.divx
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/.mkv$ $1.mkv
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/.avi$ $1.avi

Current Configuration:
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/\.(divx|mkv|avi)$ /$1.$2

Rewrite Log:
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae5c7c8/initial] (3) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] add path info postfix: F:/media/video_files/29 -> F:/media/video_files/29/.mkv
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae5c7c8/initial] (3) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] strip per-dir prefix: F:/media/video_files/29/.mkv -> 29/.mkv
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae5c7c8/initial] (3) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)/\.(divx|mkv|avi)$' to uri '29/.mkv'
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae5c7c8/initial] (2) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] rewrite '29/.mkv' -> '/29.mkv'
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae5c7c8/initial] (1) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] internal redirect with /29.mkv [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae588f8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] strip per-dir prefix: F:/media/video_files/29.mkv -> 29.mkv
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae588f8/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] applying pattern '^([0-9]+)/\.(divx|mkv|avi)$' to uri '29.mkv'
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Dec/2011:13:07:02 +0100] [video.local/sid#4518f8][rid#ae588f8/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir F:/media/video_files/] pass through F:/media/video_files/29.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

Your rewriterules seem ok... err well maybe it's the backslash. By the way you could optimize in a nicer way (not tested):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/\.(divx|mkv|avi)$ /$1.$2
```

But the only way to solve your problem (= show the whole filename) is to make a full redirect to a URL that has the full filename.

So in your case redirect would mean these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/\.(divx|mkv|avi)$ $1.$2 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

And that implies that the URLs like "14558.divx" and "1526.mkv" have to be valid and return the file.

### Two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: i have my site on a windows machine with xampp

Comment: ok i've added two hint please add the rewrite log in your question

Comment: Add the "/": **`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/\.(divx|mkv|avi)$ /$1.$2`** tell me if it works. If not could you update your "new" rewrite log" with the result of this rewrite rule?

Comment: it seems to be a cross browser bug or apache mod_rewrite bug

Comment: maybe it's the case but you know, billions of people test it everyday, so maybe it's not a bug, it's something you (and I) don't know.

Comment: and reading your log, does the file `F:/media/video_files/29.mkv` exists?

Comment: the last line of your rewrite log clearly says: it's ok, return this file: `pass through F:/media/video_files/29.mkv
`. If this file exists and it doesn't return, check your Apache error log and please add it into your question, we're close to find out why this doesn't work ;)